# Jquery not targeting item in Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a smooth scrolling effect in Rails using Jquery but I can't seem to get Jquery to target the button class. The link I'm trying to target is like this.

```
<%= link_to("#projects")  do %>
<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down fa-4x" aria-hidden="true" 
id="arrowButton" class="slideButton"></i>
<% end %>
```

and this is the jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.slideButton').click(function() {
  alert('Clicked.');
 });

});
```

when I click the link it does not create the alert.

Answer (score 1):

Your `<i>` tag has the class, not the link. You need `<%= link_to('whatever', '#projects', class: 'slideButton') %>`. Although `link_to`ing other elements by ID like that seems like an issue too.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this method,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('body').on('click', '.slideButton', function() {
  alert('Clicked.');
 });
});
```

if the element is not loaded when the intial DOM rendering, then your method will not work

Note: please tick answered if this solves your problem.

Comment: I tried this but it still ins't targeting. the pipeline is being loaded as I tested with a simple console.log.

Comment: before clicking the button, can you share your html source?